# Shell crashed with [Process completed]

Tags: git, terminal, zsh

I was doing the editing dotfile alias for the Z-Shell. This is the alias I found from dotfiles repos.

```
function gch() {
    git clone git://github.com/$USER/$1.git
}
```

then when I went to zsh, run the command like this:

```
gch benhoskings dot-files
```

What I expect to happen is

```
git clone https://github.com/benhoskings/dot-files
```

After I run that command, it output nothing but

```
[Process completed]
```

The shell freezed and ^C did not work neither. I started a new shell, all my git command crushed, like if I execute `git status`, it shows `[Process completed]` and the shell runs super-slow.

I know what I need to fix the alias function, so I could pass two params, like these

```
     function gch() {
         git clone git://github.com/$1/$2.git
     }
```

How can I kill the process running in the background? It slows down everything and cannot run any git commands. I reload the zsh by sourcing .zshrc, and tried to restart the computer to clear the current session, still cannot get rid of the Process running in the background. How can I fix it?

Comment: The `gch()` function takes only one argument; it uses `$USER` (your Unix user name) as the name of the github account, and its argument as the name of the repository. (Which seems like a bad idea; my own Unix user name doesn't match the name of my github account.) Try `gch dot-files`. Or bypass the function and try `git clone https://github.com/benhoskings/dot-files` (which works for me).

Comment: Thanks, keith. The function is serving as a short cut and I do not have to use it. The real problem here is how can I kill the background process ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have edited multiple alias. The real problem causing [Process completed] is not the function executed. it is this function I added

```
    gls() {
        query="$1"
        shift
        glog --pickaxe-regex "-S$query" "$@"
    }
```

I do not know why it is causing the shell break, but I remove the function, everything is back to normal. I freaked out for a long time when I see the [Process completed] error. Well, Who can tell me why this one breaks?

Or another question, I found from other people's dotfiles on github. sometimes it uses this format:

```
    git_current_branch() {
        cat "$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)/HEAD" | sed -e 's/^.*refs\/heads\///'
    }
```

Sometimes, it use this format with function keyword:

```
    function git_current_branch() {
        cat "$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)/HEAD" | sed -e 's/^.*refs\/heads\///'
    }
```

They both works. What is the difference between those two formats? Is it the way how you call in the CLI?

Comment: For the first question: this function definition itself can not break anything: it is just definition, so you are missing some information in your question. There is a note about it: in zsh you don’t need to quote `$@`, you can just strip all quotes from this function, add `emulate -L zsh` at the top of it (in case you have some interfering options) and it should work (though I do not know WTF is glog so it may not). For the second one: both definitions are equivalent.